# Is it necessary to upgrade to jQuery 1.4?

Tags: jquery

I have been using jQuery 1.23 till now and nowadays most of the plugins are being developed for the 1.4 version. So I just want to know is it necessary to upgrade to jQuery 1.4?

I mean all the modules I have right now, will they still work?

Comment: As long as you keep linking the old version, and need to change nothing... why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to change now  as long as things are still working.  Eventually, you will need to change because browsers change and, thus, jQuery 1.23 will someday be broken by a browser change.  I suggest that you plan on changing soon and work that into your schedule.  It's best to try and keep your software current with its dependencies.  This will make it easier to adopt new features and reduce the chance that your software will break spectacularly one day and force you to upgrade in an unplanned way.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary, but it is recommended for performance. 1.3 was a lot better than 1.2, and 1.4 is a lot better than 1.3, so 1.2 is a good bit behind.

If everything is working, and the project is not currently under development, I personally would leave it as it is. If you're moving forward with the project, I would definitely plan on upgrading jQuery.

> I mean all the modules I have right now, will they still work?

Maybe. I had to make changes to a few of my own programs, specifically regarding parsing JSON output. You'd have to test them. It's worth seeing if a new version has been released of each one that is specifically compatible with 1.4.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon this question. It is important to note one difference we recently ran into at our company when upgrading jQuery. ***The name=attribute selector has changed***.

The subtle difference? This does **NOT work** in 1.4.4+:

```
$('input[name=value]')
```

The value must have quotes. This **DOES work**:

```
$('input[name="value"]')
```

I posted a tutorial on how you can use regex to find and replace all instances of this issue.

http://nickjohnson.com/b/jquery-upgrade-how-to-fix-attribute-value-selector-errors

Answer (score 1):

No needed.. unless you'll be using a plugin or features that are supported up 1.4 onwards..

if u feel there wont be conflict with the present set up... just by replacing the jQuery source while. u can go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Resig & jQuery core developers actually did a nice job on backwards-compatibility.

But there are quite a few changes, which still might break "old" code. As an example, they changed the way `query strings` are encoded, where you explicitly have to tell jQuery (`.param()`) that you want the "old fashion" way.

Have a read:

http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14